# Robot Framework Text Validation error due to html format

Tags: python, python-2.7, robotframework, robotframework-ide

My simple assertion for robot framework is :

```
Page Should Not Contain    Master Admin Panel
```

But this test passes even when the string "Master Admin Panel" is visible on the page. Upon investigation I found that the HTML code has return character in it

```
<a href="/admin/" class="top" style=" text-decoration: none">Master
                                Admin
                                Panel</a>
```

Since it is not a straight ">Master Admin Panel<" , Robot is not able to catch it. Is there any way I can make Robot Framework to catch this and make the test Fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it doesn't contain any return characters like <*br /> but the result is in this format

Master
Admin
Panel

then you can use this

```
Page Should Not Contain Link       Master Admin Panel
```